# use integer values in one table to look up values in another SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I am looking to use integer values in a table to look up string values in another SQL table.
For example, I have two tables:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ CarType ║ CarColour ║ AbnormalCarType ║ AbnormalCarColour ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║       1 ║         1 ║ 1               ║ 2                 ║
║       1 ║         2 ║ null            ║ null              ║
║       2 ║         1 ║ 1               ║ 2                 ║
║       2 ║         2 ║ 1               ║ 1                 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

and then in the other table I have:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════╦══╗
║ CarTypeId ║ CarTypeString ║ CarColourId ║ CarColourString ║  ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══╣
║         1 ║ "Hyundai"     ║           1 ║ "Red"           ║  ║
║         1 ║ "Hyundai"     ║           2 ║ "Blue"          ║  ║
║         2 ║ "Toyota"      ║           1 ║ "Green"         ║  ║
║         2 ║ "Toyota"      ║           2 ║ "Yellow"        ║  ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════╩══╝
```

and then for the output

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ CarType ║ CarColour ║ AbnormalCarType ║ AbnormalCarColour ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Hyundai ║ Red       ║ Hyundai         ║ Blue              ║
║ Hyundai ║ Blue      ║ null            ║ null              ║
║ Toyota  ║ Green     ║ Hyundai         ║ Blue              ║
║ Toyota  ║ Yellow    ║ Hyundai         ║ Red               ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

I have tried a double inner join, first time on CarType,CarColour then on AbnormalCarType and AbnormalCarColour but it doesn't produce my desired result.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT b.CarTypeString AS CarType, b.CarColourString AS CarColour, 
  c.CarTypeString AS AbnormalCarType, c.CarColourString AS AbnormalCarColour
FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b  
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.tableA` a
ON b.CarTypeId = a.CarType AND b.CarColourId = a.CarColour
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.tableB` c
ON a.AbnormalCarType = c.CarTypeId AND a.AbnormalCarColour = c.CarColourId
```

If to apply to sample data from your example

```
WITH `project.dataset.tableA` AS (
  SELECT 1 CarType, 1 CarColour, 1 AbnormalCarType, 2 AbnormalCarColour UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 1, 1 
), `project.dataset.tableB` AS (
  SELECT 1 CarTypeId, 'Hyundai' CarTypeString, 1 CarColourId, 'Red' CarColourString UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Hyundai', 2, 'Blue' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Toyota', 1, 'Green' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Toyota', 2, 'Yellow' 
)
```

the output is as expected

```
Row CarType CarColour   AbnormalCarType AbnormalCarColour    
1   Hyundai Red         Hyundai         Blue     
2   Hyundai Blue        null            null     
3   Toyota  Green       Hyundai         Blue     
4   Toyota  Yellow      Hyundai         Red
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!
Unfortunately my minimum working example wasn't good enough and this isn't quite what I'm looking for. 
I have edited my opening post. If you have time to look again that would be great.

Comment: Btw, meantime, I tested given answer against your new sample data (assuming that `AbnormalCarColour` filed should actually be `CarColourString` as in original samples ) and it still work. anyway - please consider above suggestions

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply again and apologies for before, will keep it in mind when posting in future.